# ng-repeat in headers and angular-datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable

I have an HTML table which I want to build the most generic as possible.
I am using `jquery-datatables`, my problem is that I have try to use ng-repeat on headers of the table and `jquery-datatables` and I got an error of undefied of current data in the headers.
It is clear to me that when I ran the command `$(ID).DataTables()` in document ready it is run before angular.
The solutions for this situation is using a directive or `angular-datatables`.
But when I use `angular-datatables` with attribute `datatables="ng"` I get a strange error of loading screen. I am clueless about the solutions for this situation, I would be happy for any help.
This my code of my table which should work but doesn't work as expected.

```
<table id="gases_data_table" datatable="ng" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="gases_data_table_title" ng-repeat="header in headers">{{header}}</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="dga in listOfDGAs">
                    <td class="gases_data_table_item"  ng-repeat="detail in dga">{{detail}}</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: You need to run DataTables() after the angular has rendered. Easiest way is to put this inside a directive, then use the link function to run it.

Comment: I have search for such directive and didn't find one which do it in full scale for <td> <th> and <tr>.

Comment: never mind, I build the directive by my own.

Comment: @Brk can you share directive code plz

Comment: @Brk any solution found ? Were you able to solve the issue ?